# Always vs Every day

Tags: grammar, adverbs, word-order

> I have lunch at school *every day*
>   vs I *always* have lunch at
>   school.

Why does the frequency adverb, *always*, go before the verb, *have*, whereas the expression, "*every day*" is placed at the end of the sentence?

Comment: Michele, do you know that we have the new proposal [Italan Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42949/italian-language-usage)? I ask because, reading your name, it seems you are Italian. If so you may be intersted committing that proposal. Thank you!

Comment: Please do join Italian Language & Usage, and in the meantime I think your question would receive more attention if you were to post in [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), (English language learners). A place dedicated to people who have similar questions. I'm sure you will have a lot of help there. :)

Comment: It doesn't necessarily. You could say "Every day, I have lunch at school." or "I have lunch at school always". But you are correct that the positions you mention are more common.

Comment: @TrevorD, I think what he is asking is why “I every day have lunch at school” is ungrammatical, while “I always have lunch at school” is fine.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The question was actually why does one go "before the verb" and one "at the end of the sentence". *Grammar was not mentioned.* I was pointing out that the basic premise was wrong: "always" does not always "go before the verb"; and "every day" does not always go at the end of the sentence. OP's choices were not the *only* choices. Why have *you* chosen to interprete the question in the way you say? OP equally appears to be asking about using "always" at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the frequency phrase around pretty liberally, and still make sense:

Every day, I have lunch at school.

I, every day, have lunch at school.

I have lunch every day at school.

I have lunch at school every day.

You could even say, "I have, every day, lunch at school."  It sounds stilted to my ear, but it might be used to emphasize the repetition.

Comment: Your last suggestion has a full stop in the middle of a sentence: I'm not sure what you intended. Can you also amplify your answer to suggest moving "always" to other positions? Incidentally, I'm not sure your suggestion of "I, every day, have lunch at school." is grammatical - it sounds just as stilted as your final suggestion.

Comment: It only took me three years to fix the punctuation.

I agree that some of them sound funny, but they are all technically correct. It just depends how much attention you want to call to "every day".